# Best practice for building docker for Python - requirements file OR install individually

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker image for my Python/Django application. 
Which method would be best to follow?

#### 1.  Using requirements file

`ADD requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`

OR

#### 2. Installing packages individually

`RUN pip install package1 package2 package3
RUN pip install package4 package5`

One good thing I find with second approach is that cache can be re-used.
Each new line of pip install will added when a new version is being made, ie, one release will have at-most one line on pip install packages.

I feel that first approach will invalidate the cache as requirements file will change when new packages are added, and all the packages are re-installed.

Which method do you prefer?

Comment: It's up to your and your team, but the first method is easier to manage (since it can be generated with `pip freeze`), and it also works outside docker.

Comment: Agreed. I felt we should take the little extra pain to optimize the docker image building.